# My h2 memory database process crash, and how can i find the crash log

Tags: database, memory, crash, h2

I start the h2 server, and create a memory database by `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:databaseName;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` this jdbc string.

Then I start my server which would create a lot of db connections to h2 memory database. But unfortunately my h2 server process always crashed. I don't know why and if there is a crash log for this crash.

Comment: How did it crash (did it run out of memory, was there an exception, bluescreen, smoke)?

Comment: I don't know why, exceptions what I can see is:Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
... org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:92)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:392)
... 13 more.   and then i list the process and found the h2 process already crashed.

Comment: I would like to know if H2 database got it's own log file which would record the events such as Exceptions(include uncautchException).

Comment: This isn't a "crash", it just an exception because it couldn't connect. Do you use the exact URL you posted above? Do you have a server with the name "host", and the H2 server is running there? Otherwise try `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Comment: Yes, the jdbc string which I used is "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:databaseName;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1". And actually the exception which I mentioned before, was caused by h2 server's crash.

Comment: My point is, i want to know why it crashed. not things due to the crash.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Could you start the H2 server from the command line, so you see the exception stack trace (if there is any)? For example using `java -jar *.jar`, or using the shell script or batch file (but started from within the console, not by double clicking)